# How do you keep your macbook pro cleaned and polished?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

How often do you clean your macbook pro and what are you cleaning with?

When I bought my macbook pro last week it came with a special cloth/wipe and I've used it to wipe the dust off my screen and keyboard.

I know it would sound dumb, but what is the proper way to clean the cloth? Just wash it in water?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Several years ago I purchased the [iKlear Complete Cleaning Kit](https://www.klearscreen.com/detail.aspx?ID=99) which comes with:

- 1 - 2 oz. iKlear Spray Bottle
- 1 - 6 oz. iKlear Spray Bottle
- 1 - Large "Chamois" Cloth
- 1 - Travel Size "Chamois" Cloth
- 1 - Medium DMT Antimicrobial Cloth
- 1 - Travel Size DMT Antimicrobial Cloth
- 12 - iKlear Travel Singles

You can [buy it on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0023WU6OI) for just under $19 [prime eligible].

They claimed at the time that it was the exclusive product used at the Apple Genius Bar. I'm not sure if that's still true, but I've definitely seen it in use at Apple Stores. I've been very happy with it, and it has lasted a long, long time. ("How long?" you ask. Well, let me put it this way, I bought it for my *PowerBook.*)

The nice thing about it is that you can use it to clean the glass and the body of the Mac too.

*(Non-Disclaimer: I'm not connected to the company in any way other than a paying customer.)*

Answer (score 0):

I take it apart every 6 or so months and dust it thoroughly, and I use lens wipes for the screen. Unlike antiglare screens, the standard MacBook's screen doesn't have any special coatings and can be cleaned like any other glass.

Comment: Seriously? Take it apart? Doesn't that void AppleCare warranty?

Comment: Yes it voids it.

Comment: nope, it's within the realm of user serviceability to take off the main bottom cover to access the RAM and Hard Drive

Comment: it's 8 screws.. nbd

Answer (score 0):

Using **microfiber cloth** will to the trick most times. Unless you have dirty fingers... I clean my microfiber cloth like any other laundry in the washing machine.

When using liquids you should use ones that are **especially made for LED displays**. **Always disconnect power and remove battery when using liquids to clean**.

I personally have disassembled my my MBP several times. But there was never  so much dust that I had to clean it from the inside. My MBP is 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Spectacle cloths are perfect for every outside part of your MB. You can clean its display safely with them as well as the body and the keyboard.
Plus you can always take a few with your computer.

When I clean the keyboard of my MB I use [KeyboardCleanTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to lock it.

Comment: That's funny! I was like: "Oh, this must be some cleaning set." Then I click the link and find this app?!?! I just shut down my computer when cleaning the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Careful use of Melamine foam pads (the so-called 'magic erasers' available in generic form at most big box stores) will remove most stains and chunks of..well, whatever decomposing food mcparticles you find attached to the case itself. On the display, stick to microfiber cloths.